# Route defined in Silex but 404 error

Tags: php, silex

I use Silex framework  in my project.

I defined a road / login that points to my form of authentication to connect to the app but when I do: ipsrv / login (ipsrv being the ip web server) he does not know the road (404 ).

My app.php file (extract):

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'login' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/login',
            'anonymous' => true,
            'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/login_check'),
            'users' => $app->share(function () use ($app) {
                return new Nautilus\DAO\UserDAO($app['db']);
            })
        ),
        'general' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/',
            'anonymous' => false,
            'logout' => true
        ),
    ),
));
```

My routes.php file (extract):

```
$app->match('/login', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('login.html.twig', array(
        'error'         => $app['security.last_error']($request),
        'last_username' => $app['session']->get('_security.last_username'),
    ));
})->bind('login');
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you use these 2 files? Check the server is configured to execute your silex app, and both files are actually included there.

It works perfectly well in single-script app:

```
<?php
// web/index.php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'login'   => array(
            'pattern'   => '^/login',
            'anonymous' => true,
            'form'      => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/login_check'),
            'users'     => $app->share(function () use ($app) {
                return new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\InMemoryUserProvider();
            })
        ),
        'general' => array(
            'pattern'   => '^/',
            'anonymous' => false,
            'logout'    => true
        ),
    ),
));

$app->match('/login', function(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request) use ($app) {
    return 'login form';
})->bind('login');

$app->run();
```

When you run web server as

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t ./web/
```

`curl http://localhost:8080/login` returns "login form";

Comment: The file is used to parameterize app.php Silex, I use the firewall Silex to say that the app is protected and which they are obliged to be logged in to access the app but I say that the form is accessible all (necessary to be able to connect).
The file routes.php defined roads (entry points in the application), it redirects requests from the front controller (index.php) to good views.
The two files are included in index.php.
Twig after I use as template manager.

Comment: @DARLAIVE That's nice to know :) When I asked "How you use" I actually requested piece of your code where files are being included. Do you mind update the question with the missed part? As I have shown in the example above, your "extracts" are close to ideal and should work, if you actually use them. Don't be shy, proof you did it right and we will blame httpd configs.

Answer (score 0):

File routes.php in full :

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

// Index
$app->match('/', function () use ($app){
    return $app['twig']->render('aff_index.html.twig');
})->bind('home');

// Login form
$app->match('/login', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('login.html.twig', array(
        'error'         => $app['security.last_error']($request),
        'last_username' => $app['session']->get('_security.last_username'),
    ));
})->bind('login');
```

File app.php in full :

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler;

// Register global error and exception handlers
ErrorHandler::register();
ExceptionHandler::register();

// Register service providers.
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider());

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => array(
        __DIR__.'/../views/layout',
        __DIR__.'/../views/admin_bdd',
        __DIR__.'/../views/admin_preferences',
        __DIR__.'/../views/admin_users',
        __DIR__.'/../views/app_connexion',
        __DIR__.'/../views/app_main',
        __DIR__.'/../views/audits_mesedits',
        __DIR__.'/../views/reporting_lb',
        __DIR__.'/../views/reporting_meteo',
        __DIR__.'/../views/menu'
    )));

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\UrlGeneratorServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'login' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/login',
            'anonymous' => true,
            'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/login_check'),
            'users' => $app->share(function () use ($app) {
                return new Nautilus\DAO\UserDAO($app['db']);
            })
        ),
        'general' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/',
            'anonymous' => false,
            'logout' => true
        ),
    ),
));

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\MonologServiceProvider(), array(
    'monolog.logfile' => __DIR__.'/../var/logs/nautilus.log',
    'monolog.name' => 'Nautilus',
    'monolog.level' => $app['monolog.level']
));
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider());
if (isset($app['debug']) && $app['debug']) {
    $app->register(new Silex\Provider\HttpFragmentServiceProvider());
    $app->register(new Silex\Provider\WebProfilerServiceProvider(), array(
        'profiler.cache_dir' => __DIR__.'/../var/cache/profiler'
    ));
}

$app['dao.user'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    return new Nautilus\DAO\UserDAO($app['db']);
});
```

Index.php :

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

require __DIR__.'/../app/config/dev.php';
require __DIR__.'/../app/app.php';
require __DIR__.'/../app/routes.php';

$app->run();
```

For information I use Wamp (latest version) on Windows 10 Pro x64 with a MySQL database. And I use PhpStorm 10.0.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Xampp is incompatible with WIndows 10 (impossible to create a user: Error) and Wamp does not handle URL rewriting Windows 10. I have tested with Windows 7 and Xampp with URL rewriting and virtual hosts go well and no worries Silex roads.